# Need to whitelist ip ranges if i'm calling APIs during running test scripts on aws device farm (I'm using rest assured)

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, rest-assured, aws-device-farm

I'm using rest assured in calling APIs and as I run scripts on testing environment I need to know ip range to white list it

Answer (score 0):

You can find the appropriate ip ranges in the following two posts:

- Mobile: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/device-farm-ip-range/
- Desktop: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=928965